# Consistent Login screen in Xcode Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I managed to create an initial login screen that shows up when the app launches first. Then I save the user's info to NSUserDefaults (First name, Last name, Age, ect...). The problem is that if the user leaves blank info, and relaunches the app the initial login screen never shows up again. How can I make this login screen show up the first time my app is launched and stay there until the user fills in the appropriate info?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
{
    UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    MainViewController *firstVC = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController =firstVC;
}
else
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    // This is the first launch ever
    UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    GreetingsViewController *greetingsVC = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GreetingsViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController =greetingsVC;
}}
```

This is the code I used in my Appdelegate.m in order to set up my login screen. If maybe someone can provide me with some code in order to know what to do or how to get my login screen to work the way I want it to that would be great... Cheers.

*P.S. I set the login screen to save the user's info from a UITextField into NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of switching on the "HasLaunchedOnce" key, I'd suggest you check for the existence of username etc and decide based on that.
2. Keep in mind that user defaults is not a safe place to store sensitive information like usernames, names and passwords. These can be very easily extracted from a device without any technical skills. Use the [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) for this type of information or a wrapper [around it](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXKeychain)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.. i'll consider your method and see how successful I am with it.. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should implement login/password validators. 
You would test the login/password values before saving them. 
If null, don't allow the app to display the second screen.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `HasLaunchedOnce` as the key, use the users first name that your saving. If it's length is 0 then show the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

You add a flag called hasWrittenAllData which is set to yes and in NSUserDefaults when all the data is entered and the user pressed the next button. After that you check if the flag exists and is set to yes.
Also usernames and passwords are saved in the Keychain. For the love of Pluto (the planet) don't save them in NSUserDefaults.